# Is it enough to test my uwp app only on a single architecture?

Tags: uwp

It is an uwp app, since it is so, I want it should target all architectures. However, I face the following issue while building the project & trying to run it on my pc with AnyCPU architecture. I know how to change the targeted processor in the Configuration Manager, to bypass this error message. My question is, is it enough to test my project on a single architecture in my pc like x64 as advised in the VS error message, eventhough I want to target all architectures when distrubuted via Microsoft Store?

*Error message: The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop, Version=14.0".
Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM, ARM64".*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the architectures that UWP supports are x86, x64, ARM, and ARM64. It is recommended that target all architectures when you are developing your app. More information here: [App package architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/device-architecture).

In general, I recommend creating packages after testing on all devices with different architectures. But if you can't do that, you could just upload your package to the store because there will be tests for your app about this to make sure your app is workable for different architectures.